# Calling a remove method from custom adapter always deletes last item in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

When I want to delete a specific item from my ListView with custom adapter my last item always gets deleted and if I create a new item dynamically, it still contains the previous Spinner value.

This is my custom item xml

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/training_spinner"
        android:layout_width="255dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="19dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/delete_btn" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/delete_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:text="Delete" />


</RelativeLayout>`
```

This is my activity xml

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SelectTrainings">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/trainingsListView"
        android:layout_width="410dp"
        android:layout_height="565dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.005">

    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/TrainButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Train!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/trainingsListView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/AddTraining"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add Training"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/TrainButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/trainingsListView" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>`
```

This is the code in the activity

```
`public class SelectTrainings extends AppCompatActivity
{
    ListView trainingsListView;
    MyCustomAdapter arrayAdapter;
    Button addTraining;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_trainings);

        trainingsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.trainingsListView);
        ArrayList<Item> list = new ArrayList<Item>();
        arrayAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this, list);
        trainingsListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        addTraining = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AddTraining);
        addTraining.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                arrayAdapter.putItem();
            }
        });

        trainingsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                list.remove(i);
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    public class Item
    {
        private Spinner spinner;
        private Button button;
    }

    public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter
    {
        private ArrayList<Item> items;
        private Context context;

        public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> items) {
            super(context, 0, items);
            this.items = items;
            this.context = context;
            //Handle TextView and display string from your list
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return items.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int pos) {
            return items.get(pos);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int pos) {
            return 0;
            //just return 0 if your list items do not have an Id variable.
        }

        public void putItem() {
            items.add(new Item());
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            final Item newItem;
            if (convertView == null)
            {
                newItem = new Item();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_in_view, null);
                newItem.spinner = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.training_spinner);

                String[] stringOfPositions = new String[]{
                        "First training",
                        "Second training",
                };

                ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, stringOfPositions);
                spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                newItem.spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
                newItem.button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.delete_btn);

                convertView.setTag(newItem);
            }
            else
            {
                newItem = (Item) convertView.getTag();
            }

            newItem.button.setTag(new Integer(position));
            newItem.spinner.setTag(new Integer(position));
            newItem.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Integer tag = (Integer) v.getTag();
                    remove(getItem(tag.intValue()));
                    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });



            return convertView;
        }
    }
}`
```

How can I delete only a specific item from this list/adapter??

I have tried using tags, I have tried using onItemClickListener but nothing worked, I have also tried removing the if (convertView == null) part but that resets values in my spinners every time I add or delete a row.

EDIT: I have also realized that in my code, spinner and button are actually null. Can you help me fix that as well?

Answer (score 0):

From my observation, the major problem:

1. `MyCustomAdapter.getView()` has not passed properly the data to UI components
2. `items`, as a `Data` object shall contain value only and not UI components

---

In order to resolve the problem:

- You shall understand how `MyCustomAdapter.getView()` works

  - e.g.,
  - What the convert view is
  - How the UI component redraw after calling
    `notifyDataSetChanged()`
  - How do it relate to the `items` object

---

At last, here is my suggestion for the `Adapter` to be worked properly based on your secnario.

You may take a look and hope you get better understanding about it!

**Item class**

```
   // CHANGE: It shall store data instead of UI component.
    // UI component shall be catered by adapter and child list view component directly
    public class Item
    {
        int spinnerPosition = 0;

        //private Spinner spinner;
        //private Button button;
    }
```

**MyCustomAdapter class**

```
 public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
        private ArrayList<Item> items;
        ...
        ...
        ...
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            Log.d("MyCustomAdapter", "getView: position=" + position +
                    " " + items.get(position) +
                    " " + convertView );



            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            // EXPLAIN:
            // ConvertView == null indicates the current position is init the 1st time
            // Init it and its child view component here (once only for this position)
            // Note that this position will be re-used WHEN the dataset has changed OR screen position renew!
            if (convertView == null) {
                // Inflate parent view for current position
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_in_view, null);

                // Init child component here

                // Spinner in item_in_view
                Spinner spinner = convertView.findViewById(R.id.training_spinner);
                String[] stringOfPositions = new String[]{
                        "First training",
                        "Second training",
                        "Third training",
                        "Forth training"
                };

                // Spinner adapter
                ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, stringOfPositions);
                spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

                // Get spinner default position
                int spinnerSelectedPosition = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();

                // Store the UI component data to [item] var in instance var [this.items]
                Item item = this.items.get(position);
                item.spinnerPosition = spinnerSelectedPosition;

                // Listener to spinner item selected change
                spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                        item.spinnerPosition = position;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                    }
                });


                // Init delete button
                // Remove the instance var [this.items] position and then call notifyDataSetChanged()
                Button deleteBtn = convertView.findViewById(R.id.delete_btn);
                deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        items.remove(position);
                        //arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        // Since you are already in ArrayAdapter class, just call notifyDataSetChanged() directly!
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                // OKAY, here is the main problem
                // I am not sure the list view behaviour but I assume that it is similar to recycler view
                // ContentView will be RE-USED so we will need to put the correct data back to the spinner for current positions

                // Retrieve the data from items
                Item item = this.items.get(position);
                int expectedSpinnerSelectedPosition = item.spinnerPosition;

                // Retrieve the spinner component (As ContentView is not null, it shall be ready to call)
                Spinner spinner = convertView.findViewById(R.id.training_spinner);
                // Update the spinner selection position according to the data retrieved from items
                spinner.setSelection(expectedSpinnerSelectedPosition);
            }

            return convertView;
        }
```